# Html2pdf not supporting for large volume of data

Tags: html2pdf, large-data

I am in the process of generating a dynamic pdf file, which contains data of around 30,000 records, in general the app is developed using mySql and PHP. The dynamic content is so heavy so that, its not working with html2pdf, Is it possible to do this with html2pdf or want go with another method? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How many pages are you talking about here? (Or how many records per page).   You may find that even if you can do this that you will hit real world limits like email and web server byte limits such that you can not move it anywhere.

Comment: yeah i have added limit 1000 records..

Comment: does it worked for  30,000 records ?? me too facing the same problem